# Given a series of monotone functions which converges abs on a and b, prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_{n}(x)$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_{n}(x)$ is a series of monotone functions on $[a,b]$, and if both  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_{n}(a)$ and  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_{n}(b)$ converge absolutely, prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_{n}(x)$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$

If  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_{n}(x)$ is a series of monotone increasing functions then $|f_{n}(x)|\leq f_{n}(b)$

And since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_{n}(b)$ converges absolutely, by Weierstrass M test, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_{n}(x)$ converges absolutely and uniformly

If  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_{n}(x)$ is a series of monotone decreasing functions then $|f_{n}(x)|\leq f_{n}(a)$

And since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_{n}(a)$ converges absolutely, by Weierstrass M test, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_{n}(x)$ converges absolutely and uniformly

I'm not sure if $M_{n}$ is positive in both cases. Is this prove wrong ?

Comment: Yes your proof is wrong. To begin with, $f_n$ monotone increasing does not imply $|f_{n}(x)|\leq f_{n}(b).$

Comment: Since $f_n$ is monotonic in $[a,b]$, we have $|f(x)|\le\max(|f_n(a)|,|f_n(b)|)\le|f_n(a)|+|f_n(b)|$. Therefore, setting $M_n=|f_n(a)|+|f_n(b)|$ in the Weierstrass M-test should work.

Comment: @TravorLZH , Thanks for the suggestion. It makes sense.